# how to get hex or binary values from a wavefile in matlab?

Tags: matlab, binary, hex

i want to compute bit error rate of actual and reconstructed files. For that, what is the way to get binary or hex values from a wave file in mat lab?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you're looking for a way to read the file in binary form (that is, not ASCII). You can use [`fread`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fread.html). For example, consider the following example:

```
fid = fopen('sample.wav', 'r');  %// Open the file
A = fread(fid, 'uint8');         %// Read binary contents
fclose(fid);                     %// Close the file
```

This will read the input file "sample.wav" byte by byte (as unsigned 8-bit integers) into array `A`. Note that when you display the contents of `A` you'll see its decimal value. For instance, the byte `0x1A` would be read as decimal `26` ("hexadecimal" and "binary" are only alternative ways to represent the same value).

Once you have populated `A`, you can manipulate it by comparing it to another array of values (possibly read from another .WAV file), *etc*...

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain hexadecimal *string* representation of a number using function `dec2hex`. For binary representation there is `dec2bin`.

In general, you can find a representation for a number `d` in digit `base` format as follows:

```
d = 97; % example
base = 2; % can be 10, 16, whatever...

rep=rem(floor(d*base.^(1-ceil(log(d)/log(base)):0)),base)

% check:
rep*base.^[length(rep)-1:-1:0]'
```

It works on column vectors too.